# how to do find the toggle checkbox is check or not on button click using j query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

i have a toggle check box on my page.
i want to check if  item present in toggle check box is checked or not on click of button submit.
bellow is my code,please help me

```
    @Html.EditorForMany(model => model.AvailableLicenses, x => 
                    Model.AvailableLicenses.IndexOf(x).ToString())
```

Next

We are using mvc form post instead of ajax call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes have a `checked` attribute you can check for, which returns a boolean value. So `$('#checkBoxId').checked` will return false if not checked and true if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the checkbox checked or not in the form [submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) using JQuery.

you need to use [checked selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to check the state.